# how to get receipt information flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, revenuecat

I want to use in-app payment in flutter.
purchases_flutter package to implement it.
Is there any way to get the receipt information from the purchases_flutter package in flutter immediately after purchasing a one-time item?

I read the revenuecat documentation, but I didn't find the information because I don't know the words very well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.